# Is there one words or a better phrase to specify daily need goods

Tags: phrases, synonyms

like something to describe the commodities we use on a regular basis like stationery , coffee mugs bags, etc.

Comment: With *stationary/stationery*, remember that it is *a as in automobile*, *e as in envelope*. I think you mean *stationery*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use ***staples***: in your case it sounds like you're talking about **office staples** which shouldn't be confused with the little bits of metal used to hold documents together (which themselves would be an example of an "office staple", ie regularly bought item), but the term can be used for household shopping too.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/staples

Comment: as you said that's exactly my concern with this word

Comment: Hence the triple-joke in Staples naming its office-supplies business that.  PS: The most common and generic term is indeed "[office supplies](http://www.theonion.com/article/depot-buys-max-nations-office-supply-loving-teens--31374)".

Answer (score 3):

Consider *[necessaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/necessaries)*

> 1. (sometimes singular) what is needed; essential items: *the necessaries of life*
> 2. (law) food, clothing, etc, essential for the maintenance of a dependant in the condition of life to which he or she is accustomed

*Collins*

Answer (score 1):

A word you might consider, albeit it rather literary, is ***quotidian:***

> Ordinary or everyday; mundane:
>   *his story is an achingly human one, mired in quotidian details*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quotidian)

Your "stationery, coffee mugs, bags" and the like are quotidian needs.